# Need help in android top bar tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am stuck in creating android top bar tabs and the search bar, as the following attached image.

[image]

I have already created simple tabs with text but the line of the selected is shown downside. Now the problem is to show the icons with and the selection line should be shown upside ? How would I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom view containing a linear layout and an image . I am using a Textview and in the linear layout background attribute , i have added a drawable which is a selector for selected tab:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tabsText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_text_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dashboardtabpadding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dashboardtabpadding"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
    android:shadowDx="1.0"
    android:shadowDy="1.0"
    android:shadowRadius="2.5"
    android:textColor="@color/dashboard_tab_selector"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dashboardtab_heading_Text"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

tab_bg_selector.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--  Active tab -->
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected"
    />
    <!--  Inactive tab -->
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected"
    />
</selector>
```

and for that green part, you can use a layer list for selected and unselected tab. You can google on layer list. You can use below for selected tab :-

tab_bg_selected.xml

```
<!-- "background shadow" -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#C1C1C1" />

    </shape>
</item>
<!-- background color -->
<item
    android:top="5px">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#202222" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

and in your main activity, you can inflate the above layout and use it in the `setIndicator(View view)` method.

I hope you got it.